# The similarity of the block matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices, matrix-rank

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field,and let $A,B,C$ be matrices over $\mathbb{F}$ of respective sizes $n\times n , k\times k, $and $n\times k$.

put

$M=\begin{bmatrix}
A&0 \\ 
0&B 
\end{bmatrix}\quad $      and $\quad N=\begin{bmatrix}
A&C \\ 
0&B 
\end{bmatrix}$.

There exists a solution $X\in\mathbb{F}^{n\times k}\quad$ of $\quad AX-XB=C$ $\quad$ if and only if $\quad M$ and $N$ are similar.

- Please give some hints.

Comment: Well, my first idea would be to write down a matrix $Y = \begin{bmatrix} E & F \\ G & H \end{bmatrix}$, and assume that $Y$ conjugates $M$ to $N$, i.e. $YM = NY$. Then see what that tells you about how $E,F,G$, and $H$ relate to $A,B$, and $C$. That (I hope) should help you construct $X$ somehow.

Comment: For reference, this is referred to as [Sylvester's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $M$ and $N$ are similar.  Then we may write $MS = SN$ for some invertible matrix $S$.  That is,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A&0 \\ 
0&B 
\end{bmatrix}S = 
S
\begin{bmatrix}
A&C \\ 
0&B 
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
Now, we can assume that $S$ has (i.e. that there exists a suitable $S$ with) the block matrix form
$\begin{bmatrix}I&X\\0&Z\end{bmatrix}$ (this needs to be justified).  Multiplying through on both sides, we have the equality
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A & AX \\ 
0 & BZ 
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
A & C + XB \\ 
0 & ZB 
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
Looking at the top-right entry, we have $AX = C + XB$, which is to say that $AX - XB = C$.

---

For the converse, it suffices to show that given a particular $X$, the matrix
$$
S = 
\begin{bmatrix}
I & X\\0 & I
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Is an invertible matrix that satisfies $MS = SN$.